# Problem in converting a biginteger binary string 128 bit to an array int [4]

Tags: c++, biginteger

My method is setting bit in each elements of the int array. Althought the program works with the case where the string str="11111...111" (all the bit is 1)
However, in case as the string str="100...000" (63 zero numbers)(the first bit is 1 and the rest are 0) the problem occurs, my int array is {0,0,0,1} it has to be {0,0,1,0}
Please give me a solution with my code, if your idea is better, tell me so i can fix the problem soon.

```
int arr[4]={0};
void convert(string str)
    {

        int length = str.length();
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (str[i] == '1')
            {
                int pos = 3 - i / 32;
                int k;
                k = (length - i - 1) % 31;
                //if (i == 0)
                //{
                //pos = 2- length/32;
                //}
                arr[pos] = (1 << k) | arr[pos];
            }
        }
    }
```

If the string has 1000...00 (32 0 numbers ), the int array has to be {0,0,1,0}
If the string has 1000...00 (63  0 numbers), the int array has to be {0,1,0,0}

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: what is "the problem" ? btw using `std::bitset` makes bit fiddling much simpler

Comment: half of this sentence seems to be missing: "However, in case as the string str="100...000" (...)" .. what happens in that case?

Comment: You probably should verify that your input string is not longer than 128 characters.

Comment: I think you should separate the two concerns of your algorithm. First define a "biginteger" type and provide basic operators that work as if you were using a regular integer. Then write the conversion from bit-string using that type. You should also use an array of `uint32_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: You correctly set the bits when they are 1, but never reset them when they are 0, hence the problem. A very simple way would be to zero the 4 integers before entering the loop.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have already set all the elements of the array 0.

Comment: @user463035818 i've updated the post. Sorry for my obmission. Please read the post again

Comment: That pointer you’re returning becomes invalid as soon as the function returns. Return `std::array` or pass the array into the function.

Comment: This is even worse: you are returning a pointer on an automatic array! The lifetime of `arr` ends when the function returns and using it in caller invokes Undefined Behaviour. Pass an array from the caller, and use it in function..

Comment: Is the problem you are using a little endian system? https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~arch111/wiki.files/Lectures_pdf/Big.pdf

Comment: To clarify: if you're observing the result through the returned pointer, your code has undefined behaviour and the observation is meaningless.

Comment: Change `int* arr=new int[4]; arr={0};` to `int* arr=new int[4]{};`

Comment: Regardless of what you feed that function, the leading `'1'` has index 0, so its `pos` is always 3. (I'm not posting that as an answer since there are more problems for you to work out.)

Comment: @molbdnilo i saw it and i tried to fix by the way adding some conditions in the loop but it's still wrong. When 1 case is right, the previous one is wrong.

Comment: @F.Wu Attempts to fix bugs by adding code are very seldom successful. Sit down and work out the logic (preferrably away from the keyboard) instead of trying to handle special cases.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for your adviece. I have found the answer. Please review my code below and let me know if something goes wrong or some cases make errors.

Answer (score 0):

So i have found a solution for my own problem. Please help me test my code then let me know if any test cases make errors. Thank you.

```
class QInt
{
private:
    int Data[4];
public:
QInt(){

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Data[i] = 0;
    }

}

QInt QInt::StrBinToQInt(string str)
{
    QInt temp=QInt();
    str = creString128(str);
    cout << str.length() << endl;
    cout << str << endl;
    for (int i = 127; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int pos;
        if (str[i] == '1')
        {
            pos = i / 32;
            int k = (127-i) % 32;
            if (i % 32 == 0)
            {
                pos--;
                k = 0;
            }
            if (str[0] == '1')
            {
                pos = 0;
                k = 30;
            }
            temp.Data[pos] = (1 << k) | temp.Data[pos];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

};

string creString(int n)
{
    string temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp += '0';
    }
    return temp;
}

string creString128(string bin)
{
    string corrBin = creString(128 - bin.length());
    corrBin += bin;
    return corrBin;
}
```